# How do I redirect users not logged in using DevLess JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, backend

I'm using the [**DevLess**](https://github.com/DevlessTeam/DV-JS-SDK) javascript sdk for development, and I would like to do redirection on some pages in case a user is not logged in. **Help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DevLess SDK provides a profile method which you can call on to verify if a user is logged in or not ie. `SDK.call('devless', 'profile', [], function(resp){console.log(res)})` 
You may handle the redirects with the example below

```
 SDK.call('devless', 'profile', [], function(resp){
          user_id = resp.payload.result.id;
          if(resp.payload.result == undefined || resp.payload.result.last_name != 'C'){
            window.location.href="/auth/login/";
          } 
        })
```

https://github.com/DevlessTeam/DV-JS-SDK